# Linq for sql server reporting services, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Is it possible to use my existing Linq data model for server side reporting (sql server 2005 reporting services)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to write a DataProcessing extension that would be deployed to your report server and designer.

Here is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/SSRS2005XML.aspx).